# Can't print elements of BST at a given level in reverse order

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search-tree

I am trying to write a code, which, given a Binary Search Tree root and a level, prints out the elements of the tree at that level. This is working fine:

```
def myprint(root,level):
    if root:
        if not level:
            print root.data,
        else:
            myprint(root.left,level-1)
            myprint(root.right,level-1)
```

However, when I try to tweak it to print the elements at a level in reverse order, it dosn't work. For the following tree:

```
                         26
                    /          \
                   13          39
                  /  \        /  \
                 6    19     32   51
                / \   / \    / \  / \
               4   8  14    31 33   68
                        \
                         17
```

if I want to output the elements at level 3 (level of root is 0) from right to left, the output should be `68 33 31 14 8 4`. The code above does the reverse correctly, that is, prints out `4 8 14 31 33 68`. But the below code doesn't print the reverse order correctly, and prints out `31 33 68 4 8 14` instead:

```
def revprint(root,level):
    if root:
        if not level:
            print root.data,
        else:
            myprint(root.right,level-1)
            myprint(root.left,level-1)
```

Can anybody spot the error, and tell me how to rectify it? The code for initializing the tree is as follows:

```
class tree:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.successor,self.left,self.right = None,None,None
    def push(self,data):
        root = self
        while root:
            oldroot = root
            if root.data > data:
                root = root.left
            elif root.data < data:
                root = root.right
        if data > oldroot.data:
            oldroot.right = tree(data)
        else:
            oldroot.left = tree(data)

a = tree(26)
for x in [13,39,6,19,4,8,5,10,9,14,17,15,32,51,68,31,33,36,34]:
a.push(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `myprint` in `revprint`. The fixed version of `revprint`:

```
def revprint(root,level):
    if root:
        if not level:
            print root.data,
        else:
            revprint(root.right,level-1)
            revprint(root.left,level-1)
```

Comment: Come on now, of course I can do that! What I want to know is why isn't the code working!

Comment: Can you then provide the code that initializes your tree? In this case at least it would be possible to test.

Comment: I can, but that is hardly necessary here. Each node has three attributes - `left`, `right` and `data`. I call the function using the root and the level: `revprint(root,level)`.

Comment: It is necessary: do you think people who could potentially help you would like to type 20 lines of code themselves just to initialize your tree to test the code?

Answer (score 2):

```
Here my code prints the tree level by level as well as upside down

int counter=0;// to count the toatl no. of elments in the tree


void tree::print_treeupsidedown_levelbylevel(int *array)
{
int j=2;  
int next=j;
int temp=0;
while(j<2*counter)
{
    if(array[j]==0)
    break;

    while(array[j]!=-1)
    {
        j++;
    }

    for(int i=next,k=j-1 ;i<k; i++,k--)
    {
        temp=array[i];
        array[i]=array[k];
        array[k]=temp;
    }

    next=j+1;
    j++;
}

for(int i=2*counter-1;i>=0;i--)
{
    if(array[i]>0)
    printf("%d ",array[i]);

    if(array[i]==-1)
    printf("\n");
}
} 

void tree::BFS()
{
queue<node *>p;

node *leaf=root;

int array[2*counter];
for(int i=0;i<2*counter;i++)
array[i]=0;

int count=0;

node *newline=new node; //this node helps to print a tree level by level
newline->val=0;
newline->left=NULL;
newline->right=NULL;
newline->parent=NULL;

p.push(leaf);
p.push(newline);

while(!p.empty())
{
    leaf=p.front();
    if(leaf==newline)
    {
        printf("\n");
        p.pop();
        if(!p.empty())
        p.push(newline);
        array[count++]=-1;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<leaf->val<<" ";
        array[count++]=leaf->val;

        if(leaf->left!=NULL)
        {
            p.push(leaf->left);
        }
        if(leaf->right!=NULL)
        {
            p.push(leaf->right);
        }
        p.pop();
    }
}
delete newline;

print_treeupsidedown_levelbylevel(array);
}


 Here in my code the function BFS prints the tree level by level, which 
 also fills the data in an int array for printing the tree upside down.
(note there is a bit of swapping is used while printing the tree upside down 
 which helps to achieve our goal). 
 if the swaping is not performed then for a tree like

                     8
                   /  \
                  1    12
                  \     /
                   5   9
                 /   \
                4     7
                     /
                    6
  o/p will be
  6
  7 4
  9 5
  12 1
  8

  but the o/p has to be
  6
  4 7
  5 9
  1 12
  8

  this the reason why swapping part wass needed in that array.
```

Comment: That's good work. But the method I mentioned, or by simply using a stack, this can be accomplished much more concisely...

Comment: I can remove usage of the array,but the code will become much more stringent than before.